# How to notify pandas DataFrame modification?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data stored in pandas DataFrame objects, which are used in several places in my software, either for graph plot or table view. The data are modifiable, but I'd like to update every component when a modification occurs on a DataFrame.

**So is there a way to get a signal, an event or set a callback on a DataFrame to perform some action whenever a modification occurs?**

Modification can be a single value change, multiple values change, data insertion or deletion. I'm using python 3.6.2 and pandas 0.21.0 (and PyQt5 but it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

Is polling an option?

```
_old_df = None
def poll_func(df):
    if df is not None and (_old_df is None or not df.equals(_old_df)):
        _old_df = df.copy()
        update_other_components()
```

Then have a thread run this function every X seconds.